# jquery - zoom in/ out pages

Tags: jquery

Every time when I click on the link I need to "zoom out" the previous page and "zoom in" current page.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/allegrissimo123/uhpo6cw4/1/)

```
$('.nav li a, .subscribenow a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();    

   var item = "#" + $(this).attr('data-href');
   $('#home').removeClass('zoomIn').addClass('zoomOut');      
   $(item).removeClass('zoomOut').show().addClass('zoomIn');

});
```

Comment: What do you mean zoom? Zoom is not a default jquery animaltion....so you will have to explain.

Comment: I am using https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/